# Server-side permanent state management

Tags: c#, asp.net, switch-statement, state, backend

I am looking for an easy way to handle permanent states in my server-side code.

There are a few things I have to consider:

- The state is stored in a database
- There are different states for different objects which is handled differently

This means that I eg. have two different types of objects `Models` and `Parameters`, each of these objects has a state property which is stored in my database.

When the frontend calls one of my public functions I need to validate the current state of the given object in order to see if the action is valid.

What is the best way to handle this in my backend?

**Original Attempt**

```
public class StateManager
{
    bool HandleState<T>(T state);
}
```

which would be called somewhat like this

```
myStateManager.HandleState<ModelState>(GetStateFromDatabase(myModelId));
```

and be implemented like this

```
bool HandleState<T>(T state)
{
   switch(T)
   {
       case ModelState:
           switch(state) 
           {
               case ModelState.Ready:
                  return true;
           }  
      case ParameterState:
          switch(state)
          {
              case ParameterState.Ready:
                  return true;
          }    
   }
}
```

***The solution above does not work since I can't case on `T` as it is an Enum type, and not a simple type.***

I am looking for something which is easily extended, both with new types of states, but also new state values.

Comment: So to recap: "How do I store stuff in a database?" It's a very broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I readded my initial idea which shows what I am trying to achive, but is not possible in the format showed. To recap: I am NOT looking for a way to store the state - I already got that. I am looking for a way to make a validate method which I can call when the backend recives a call to see if it is valid to execute (based on state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible solution:
a factory that produces an object implementing a generic state handler interface that accepts T ... and x implementations that handle the enums ...

standard stuff for most ioc containers i know...

register the implementations of the state handler interface via ioc

call your factory to get the right implementation

easy to implement even without an ioc container (let me know if you need an example, in case your googlefoo is insuficient)

example:

```
namespace playground
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var testcase1 = DummyStateType1.State1;
            var testcase2 = DummyStateType2.OtherState1;

            var handler1 = StateHandlerFactory<DummyStateType1>.Create();
            var handler2 = StateHandlerFactory<DummyStateType2>.Create();

            var result1 = handler1.handle(testcase1);
            var result2 = handler2.handle(testcase2);

            var alsoResult1 = tadaaaa(testcase1);
            var alsoResult2 = tadaaaa(testcase2);
        }
        static bool tadaaaa<T>(T state)
        {
            return StateHandlerFactory<T>.Create().handle(state);
        }
    }
    public interface IStateHandler<T>
    {
        bool handle(T state);
    }
    public enum DummyStateType1
    {
        State1,
        State2
    }
    public enum DummyStateType2
    {
        OtherState1,
        OtherState2
    }
    public static class StateHandlerFactory<T>
    {
        public static IStateHandler<T> Create()
        {
            //this could be replaced by IoC ... or a reflection based lookup ... you name it...
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (type == typeof(DummyStateType1))
                return (IStateHandler<T>)new DummyStateType1StateHandler();
            if (type == typeof(DummyStateType2))
                return (IStateHandler<T>)new DummyStateType2StateHandler();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public class DummyStateType1StateHandler : IStateHandler<DummyStateType1>
    {
        public bool handle(DummyStateType1 state)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case DummyStateType1.State1:
                    return false;
                case DummyStateType1.State2:
                    return true;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
    public class DummyStateType2StateHandler : IStateHandler<DummyStateType2>
    {
        public bool handle(DummyStateType2 state)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case DummyStateType2.OtherState1:
                    return true;
                case DummyStateType2.OtherState2:
                    return false;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could sketch your solution it would be appreciated :)

Comment: @M.Larsen ... here you go

Comment: but please keep in mind that it has no compiletime safety ... the compiler does not know if you use something for T that does not have an actual implementation ...

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution for it's extensibility, but I was originally looking for a solution where once instance of a class could handle both `DummyStateType1` and `DummyStateType2` without creating seperate instances of the StateManager. I did though also look for a lightweight way to check for states, which contradicts the idea of handling "too much", so I went with your solution and extended it is needed.

Comment: the idea is "separation of concerns" ... one class is concerned with one state enum ...if you want it "smaller" like no extra classes per enum, you could go with delegates and instead of a IStateHandler<T>, go with some Func<T,Bool> and have one class provide all the Func<> instances ... but i'd call that a mess once it gets bigger ...